# ContainerAlreadyOnlease error while restoring a vm using powershell azure

Tags: powershell

I am trying to restore a vm in azure using powershell. But I get a Disk preparation error:

> There is already a lease on storage container holding the blob with uri https:// < .vhd uri > . ContainerAlreadyOnLease.

There is no lease on the container nor the blob holding the `.vhd's`. Please help me with the solution for this

Comment: At the very least you will need to show the cide that you are running.

Comment: I didnt get u. Cide means?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Cide = Code